# What is the equation of a conic section, relative to its vertices.

Tags: geometry

What is the equation of the conic section shown below? The distance between the covertices is 1. In addition to $a$ and $b$ there must be a third variable which determines the shape of the curve.

Note: in hyperbolas and some ellipses, the horizontal line will connect the vertices, rather than the covertices.

I have completely rewritten and shortened this question for clarity.

[image: Ellipse oriented vertically, with an inscribed triangle. The minor axis has length 1, and the remaining sides have lengths a and b.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: There is just one degree of freedom for the family of conic, namely $$4x^2+By^2=1$$

Comment: For $a=b$, the conic is clearly unique. For $a\neq b$ ... If you flip the triangle vertically, and likewise flip it horizontally, keeping the "$1$" sides aligned, you'll have five points through which the conic passes; the conic is still unique. No extra parameter is needed. ... In any case, please include the work you've done to solve the problem, and indicate where you got stuck. You might provide additional context such as the tools allowed (trig?). This will help people avoid explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your current level.

Comment: This actually was a better question in some ways before it was shortened, since there were at least some cases of formulas you had worked out yourself. I refer to those formulas in my answer.

Comment: At one point you had an example where the "equation of the conic" was $a^2+b^2=1$, which (to me) strongly suggests that the conic is defined without the triangle (by means of your "third variable") and then you inscribe triangles with one vertex placed arbitrarily on the conic to get sides $a$ and $b$ for many different values of $a$ and $b.$ The latest edit gives not even a hint of this interpretation: it looks like you have two points that you know are vertices or covertices and you know the distances $a$ and $b$ to one other point.

Comment: For most people, an "equation of a conic" is something like $4x^2+2y^2=1$ where the way you can tell a point is on the conic is that its Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ satisfy the equation. But $x$ and $y$ are not distances to any particular points and certainly not distances to vertices or covertices of the conic. So if you actually want an equation giving a relationship between those distances you need to say something about that. Or was $a^2+b^2=1$ not really the kind of "equation" you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've chosen somewhat inconvenient variable names, because $a$ and $b$ are typically used as constant parameters of an ellipse or hyperbola: each would be half the length of one of the axes.

Instead, half the length of one of the axes of your ellipse is $\frac12.$ Let's say that $h$ is half the length of the other axis. Then if we put the two covertices on a Cartesian plane at the points $\left(-\frac12,0\right)$ and $\left(\frac12,0\right),$ the vertices are at $(0,h)$ and $(0,-h)$ and the equation of the ellipse is

$$ \frac{x^2}{(1/2)^2} + \frac{y^2}{h^2} = 1. $$

If $0<h<1$ then the vertices are on the $x$ axis and the covertices on the $y$ axis.
If we change the $+$ to $-$ then we have the formula of a hyperbola with vertices at $\left(-\frac12,0\right)$ and $\left(\frac12,0\right)$ and covertices at $(0,h)$ and $(0,-h).$

We can write the equation of any of these conics as
$$ 4h^2 x^2 \pm y^2 = h^2, \tag1$$
with $+$ for an ellipse and $-$ for a hyperbola.
(This excludes the line segment between vertices and the two opposing rays, which generally are not considered conics. But those cases can be filled in later without using this equation.)

Now let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary point on the conic and let $a$ and $b$ be the distances from $(x,y)$ to the two points $\left(-\frac12,0\right)$ and $\left(\frac12,0\right),$ respectively.
By the Pythagorean Theorem,

\begin{align}
 a^2 &= \left(x + \frac12\right)^2 + y^2 = x^2 + x + \frac14 + y^2,  \tag2\\
 b^2 &= \left(x - \frac12\right)^2 + y^2 = x^2 - x + \frac14 + y^2.  \tag3
\end{align}

Subtract each side of Equation $(3)$ from each side of Equation $(2)$:
$$ a^2 - b^2 = 2x, $$
so
$$ x^2 = \frac14(a^2 - b^2)^2. \tag4$$

But adding the equations instead,
$$ a^2 + b^2 = 2x^2 + \frac12 + 2y^2, $$
which we can rearrange to
$$
y^2 = \frac12(a^2 + b^2) - x^2 - \frac14
    = \frac12(a^2 + b^2) - \frac14(a^2 - b^2)^2 - \frac14. \tag5
$$

An equation with only $x^2$ or $y^2$ in it tells us nothing about the sign of $x$ or $y,$ but that's appropriate since the symmetry of the conic ensures that if $(x,y)$ is on the conic then so are $(-x,y),$ $(x,-y),$ and $(-x,-y).$

If we use Equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ to substitute into Equation $(1),$ we get

$$
h^2 (a^2 - b^2)^2
\pm \left(\frac12(a^2 + b^2) - \frac14(a^2 - b^2)^2 - \frac14\right)
 = h^2
$$

where the $\pm$ is $+$ for an ellipse, $-$ for a hyperbola.
That is, for an ellipse this reduces to
$$
\left(h^2 - \frac14\right) (a^2 - b^2)^2 + \frac12(a^2 + b^2)
 = h^2 + \frac14 \tag6
$$
while for a hyperbola it is
$$
\left(h^2 + \frac14\right) (a^2 - b^2)^2 - \frac12(a^2 + b^2)
 = h^2 - \frac14. \tag7
$$

This matches some of the results you got previously:
for the ellipse with $h=\frac12,$ which is a circle, Equation $(6)$ is equivalent to $a^2 + b^2 = 1,$
whereas in the limit as $h$ goes to infinity,
where both the ellipse and the hyperbola approach two parallel straight lines, both Equations $(6)$ and $(7)$ approach
$(a^2 - b^2)^2 = 1,$
which is equivalent to $(a^2 - b^2 - 1)(a^2 - b^2 + 1) = 0,$
which says that either $a^2 = b^2 + 1$ or $b^2 = a^2 + 1.$

Unfortunately, for $\lvert h \rvert < \frac12,$ things get messy:
in addition to the correct values of $a$ and $b,$
Equations $(6)$ and $(7)$ are satisfied by some pairs of values $a,b$ that cannot be found on the conic.
If you plot the solutions $(a,b)$ as Cartesian coordinates,
the values for the ellipse should form a simple closed loop around the origin and the value for the hyperbola should lie on four branches (which look vaguely hyperbolic, but are not) that are asymptotic to lines with slope $1$ or $-1$ (a set of four lines, of which each branch is asymptotic to two lines),
but for $\lvert h \rvert < \frac12$ the graphs of both equations consist of five components: one loop around the origin and four branches asymptotic to the four lines.
So in addition to the Equation $(6)$ or $(7)$ you would need to specify some condition such as $a^2 + b^2 \leq 1$ or $a^2 + b^2 \geq 1$ in order to exclude spurious solutions.

Fortunately, a sufficient condition for excluding spurious solutions is simply that $a$ and $b$ are a possible pair of distances from one point to the two points $\left(-\frac12,0\right)$ and $\left(\frac12,0\right)$;
that is, they must be possible sides of a triangle whose third side is $1.$
In the spurious solutions, either $\lvert a - b\rvert > 1$ or $a + b < 1,$
so no such triangle could exist.
Therefore if you plot a figure using Equations $(6)$ or $(7)$ to describe distances from the two covertices or vertices, you get just an ellipse or a hyperbola.

If we set $h = 0$ we get just the four lines, that is, both equations then are equivalent to
$$ (a - b - 1) (a - b + 1) (a + b - 1) (a + b + 1) = 0. $$
If you make the restriction that $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0,$
this equation can be satisfied either when
$a + b = 1,$ which gives you the line segment between
$\left(-\frac12,0\right)$ and $\left(\frac12,0\right),$
or when
$(a - b - 1) (a - b + 1) = 0,$
which gives you the two rays in opposite directions, that is, the points where $a = b + 1$ or $b = a + 1.$

Comment: David K, thank you for fixing my question and for your answer, which I will study. Let me add a bit of context. I was thinking about spheroids in relation to the method of drawing an ellipse with a string attached to the foci. This method can also produce a prolate spheroid, but it cannot produce an oblate spheroid. Hence I was looking for a way to define an oblate spheroid  relative to two given points.

Comment: David K, could you suggest better variable names instead of a and b? I have another, similar question, and I want to use accepted notation.

Comment: I don't know of any "standard" names for these two distances. I've seen various names for the distances from a point to the to focal points, such as $d_1$ and $d_2$; $r_1$ and $r_2$; or $r$ and $r'$. Those aren't really "standard" either so you could repurpose them. But if you just want two plain letters without subscripts or other decoration, maybe $u$ and $v$, since $v$ stands for "vertex."

Comment: There isn't any strict rule about which letters you use, but very frequently $a$ is the semi-major axis and $b$ is the semi-minor axis. Also, people like to write the equations of ellipses in Cartesian coordinates $x$ and $y.$ So I'd suggest staying away from those four letters in particular (unless you use them for the "usual" purposes) just because people could jump to incorrect conclusions from the habit of using those letters a particular way.

Comment: David K, after some thought, I re-submitted the problem as a new question, so that the "third variable" doesn't have to go to infinity. I don't expect you to re-do your calculations, but any comment would be appreciated. Link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449421/define-a-conic-section-relative-to-its-vertices?noredirect=1#comment9317606_4449421

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, lengths $a$ and $b$ (and assumptions about position and orientation) are sufficient to determine the conic; no additional parameters are needed. Here's a trigonometric approach to finding the equation:

To help keep track of the contributions of the triangle's base to the calculations, and to avoid fractions, let's say it has length $2c$; for that matter, let's go ahead and name the triangle $\triangle ABC$ in the standard way. Then, for a conic centered at the origin with axes of symmetry aligned with the coordinate axes, the equation has the form
$$\frac{x^2}{c^2}+\frac{y^2}{d^2}=1 \tag1$$
for some $d^2$, which we'll allow to be negative for a hyperbola.

The apex, $C$, of the triangle has coordinates $(x,y)=\left(-c+a\cos B, a\sin B\right)$. Substituting into $(1)$, we readily solve for $d^2$, which we simplify using various trig relations:
$$d^2 = \frac{a c^2 \sin^2B}{\cos B (c - a \cos B)}=\frac{a}{b}\frac{c^2\sin^2 B}{\cos A\cos B}=\frac{\sin A}{\sin B}\frac{c^2\sin^2 B}{\cos A\cos B}=c^2\tan A\tan B \tag{2}$$
Consequently, we can write $(1)$ as
$$x^2+y^2\cot A\cot B = c^2 \tag3$$

Some notes:

- For $A$ and $B$ acute, the coefficient $\cot A\cot B$ is positive and the conic is an ellipse. If, in particular, $A$ and $B$ are *complementary* (so that $C$ is a right angle), then $\cot A\cot B =1$ and the conic is a circle (as expected from [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem)).
- If $A$ or $B$ is obtuse (at most one of them *can* be), then the coefficient is negative and the conic is an hyperbola.
- If either $A$ or $B$ is right, then the coefficient vanishes and the conic degenerates into the "parallel lines" parabola, $x^2=c^2$.
- There's an interesting geometric interpretation to relation $(2)$. For an ellipse (the hyperbola case is left to the reader), let (extended) segments $AC$ and $BC$ meet the vertical axis at $A'$ and $B'$, respectively. Then $|OA'|= c\tan A$ and $|OB'|=c\tan B$, and $(2)$ asserts
  $$d^2 = |OA'|\,|OB'|$$ That is, $d$ is the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) of $|OA'|$ and $|OB'|$.

[image]

Note that the geometric mean property is true for $A'$ and $B'$ determined by any $C$ on the conic. There's connection here with [poles and polars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar), of which I wasn't previously aware. Nifty!