# Define a conic section relative to its vertices

Tags: geometry

What is the equation of a conic section illustrated below. Points $A$ and $B$ are the vertices, separeted by a distance of $1$, and point $C$ is an arbitrary point on the conic. Point $A$ is also the center of a circle which passes through $O$, the center of the conic. Point $C'$ is the special case of point $C$ where the conic intersects that circle.

The equation should show the relationship between the lengths of segments $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$, and a third variable which defines the shape of the conic. For example, in the special case where the conic is a circle (no third variable used), the equation is: $\overline{AC}^2 + \overline{BC}^2 = 1$. For the degenerate case where the conic is an infinitely thin ellipse which becomes a line segment (no third variable necessary) the equation is: $\overline{AC} + \overline{BC} = 1$. For the degenerate case of an infinetely tall ellipse which becomes two parallel lines, the equation is $\overline{AC}^2 + 1= \overline{BC}^2$ or  $\overline{BC}^2 + 1= \overline{AC}^2$. For the case of the degenerate hyperbola where the solution is two opposed rays, the equation is $\overline{AC} - \overline{BC} = 1$ or $\overline{BC} - \overline{AC} = 1$

I had asked the question nearly this way in my previous StackExchange post, and it was properly answered, but the answer was two equations - one for a hyperbola and one for an ellipse. The "third variable" had to go to infinity for the degenerate case of an infinitely tall ellipse which becomes parallel lines. I am therefore including suggestions for the third variable so that the answer is a single equation. Here are three fairly obvious suggestions for the third variable:

The measure of angle $\angle BAC'$

The length of segment $\overline{BC'}$

The length of segment $\overline{OC'}$    (I'm thinking that an isosceles triangle might keep the math simpler.)

I've assumed that the distance between $A$ and $B$ is 1, though that may not be optimum. And for the nitpickers, the vertices shown here are actually co-vertices.

[image: A conic section, (here an ellipse) with vertices A and B. Circle A passes through the origin. A triangle is inscribed in the conic with additional point C. C' is the point where the conic intersects the circle.]

Comment: For people wanting to know our previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4430863/305862 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [an answer to the previous related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4430863/139123), writing $a = AC$ (length of the segment $\overline{AC}$)
and $b = BC$ (length of the segment $\overline{BC}$), there are separate equations for the ellipse and for the hyperbola,
$$
\left(h^2 - \frac14\right) (a^2 - b^2)^2 + \frac12(a^2 + b^2) = h^2 + \frac14
$$
and
$$
\left(h^2 + \frac14\right) (a^2 - b^2)^2 - \frac12(a^2 + b^2) = h^2 - \frac14,
$$
respectively.
In addition, there is the case of two vertical lines through the points $A$ and $B$,
which has the equation
$$
(a^2 - b^2 - 1)(a^2 - b^2 + 1) = 0,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
(a^2 - b^2)^2 = 1.
$$

Note that all of these equations can be written in the form
$$
p (a^2 - b^2)^2 + (q - p)(a^2 + b^2) = q \tag 1
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are real constants. So if we want to come up with a single equation that covered all three cases, we can clearly do it if we get to choose $p$ and $q$ independently at will.

Some other observations: for the hyperbola, $p > q,$ for the ellipse, $p < q,$ and for the vertical lines, $p = q.$ For the extreme cases of the degenerate hyperbola and ellipse, $p = -q.$
But note that only the ratio between $p$ and $q$ really matters, because
if we multiply both $p$ and $q$ by the same non-zero factor we get an equation with the same solutions for $a$ and $b$ as before.

If we want to come up with a single equation where we select just a single parameter value to determine the shape of the graph, we need formulas for $p$ and $q$ in terms of that parameter that allow all of the necessary ratios to be achieved.

---

Any of the parameters in the question should work, but let's try the parameter
$\beta = BC'$ (the length of the segment $\overline{BC'}$).

The figure tells us that at one of the points on the desired curve we have
$a = \frac12$ and $b = \beta.$
If we plug those values into the generic formula in Equation $(1)$, we have
$$
p \left(\left(\tfrac12\right)^2 - \beta^2\right)^2 + (q - p)\left(\left(\tfrac12\right)^2 + \beta^2\right) = q.
$$

Multiply everything by $4$ so we don't have to deal with powers of $\frac12,$
expand $(1 - 4\beta^2)^2$, collect all the $p$ terms on one side and all the $q$ terms on the other, and we get something equivalent to
$$ (12 - 16 \beta^2) q = (3 + 24 \beta^2 - 16 \beta^4) p. $$

An easy way to make this true for any value of $\beta$ is to set
\begin{align}
p &= 12 - 16 \beta^2, \\
q &= 16 \beta^4 - 24 \beta^2 - 3.
\end{align}

Making these substitutions for $p$ and $q$ in Equation $(1)$ and simplifying the difference $q - p$ we get:
$$
(12 - 16 \beta^2) (a^2 - b^2)^2 + (16 \beta^4- 8 \beta^2 - 15)(a^2 + b^2)
 = 16 \beta^4 - 24 \beta^2 - 3. \tag2
$$

If we let $\beta$ range through all values between $\frac12$ and  $\frac32$ (that is, all the distances from $B$ to any point on the circle around $A$),
we get the full range of ellipses and hyperbolas,
with a circle for $\beta = \frac{\sqrt3}2$ (where $\beta$ is the leg opposite $A$ in a right triangle $\triangle AC'B$)
and parallel lines for $\beta = \frac{\sqrt5}2$ (where $\beta$ is the hypotenuse of a right triangle $\triangle BAC'$).

---

To use the measure of the angle $\angle BAC'$ as the single parameter, let that angle be $\theta.$
Then at the point $C'$, we have $a = \tfrac12$ (again) and
$b^2 = \left(\tfrac12\right)^2 + 1^2 - 2\cdot \tfrac12\cdot 1\cdot \cos\theta
 = \tfrac54 - \cos\theta$
by the Law of Cosines.
Making these substitutions for $a$ and $b^2$ in Equation $(1)$, we get

$$
p \left(\cos\theta - 1\right)^2 + (q - p)\left(\tfrac32 - \cos\theta\right) = q
$$

Expanding and collecting terms in $p$ and $q$, we can arrive at the equivalent equation
$$
 q (1 - 2 \cos\theta) = p (1 + 2 \cos\theta - 2\cos^2\theta),
$$
from which we can find suitable values for $p$ and $q$:
\begin{align}
p &= 1 - 2 \cos\theta, \\
q &= 1 + 2 \cos\theta - 2\cos^2\theta.
\end{align}

Putting these values into Equation $(1)$ and simplifying, we have
$$
(1 - 2 \cos\theta) (a^2 - b^2)^2 + (4 \cos\theta - 2\cos^2\theta)(a^2 + b^2)
 = 1 + 2 \cos\theta - 2\cos^2\theta. \tag3
$$
We get the full set of ellipses and hyperbolas by letting $\theta$ range from $0$ to $\pi,$ corresponding to all possible locations of the point $C'$ along the upper half of the circle about $A.$
The circle occurs at $\theta = \frac\pi3$
and the two parallel lines occur at $\theta = \frac\pi2.$

It should also be possible to derive Equation $(3)$ by substituting
$\beta = \tfrac54 - \cos\theta$ in Equation $(2).$

---

Let $d = OC'$, the length of the segment $\overline{OC'}$.
Using the definition of the angle $\theta$ from above, we can write
$d = \sin\frac\theta2.$
Therefore the double-angle formula for the cosine
(interpreting $\theta$ as double the angle $\frac\theta2$) implies that
$\cos\theta = 1 - 2\sin^2\frac\theta2 = 1 - 2d^2.$
If we make this substitution for $\cos\theta$ in Equation $(3),$ we get
$$
(1 - 2 (1 - 2d^2)) (a^2 - b^2)^2 + (4 (1 - 2d^2) - 2(1 - 2d^2)^2)(a^2 + b^2)
 = 1 + 2 (1 - 2d^2) - 2(1 - 2d^2)^2,
$$
which simplifies to
$$
(4 d^2 - 1) (a^2 - b^2)^2 + (2 - 8 d^4)(a^2 + b^2) = 1 + 4 d^2 - 8 d^4. \tag 4
$$

For this formula we get the full range of ellipses and hyperbolas by letting $d$ range between $0$ and $1,$ which is the range of possible lengths of chords of the circle about $A$. The circle occurs at $d = \frac12$ and the two parallel lines occur at $d = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}.$

---

Any of Equations $(2)$, $(3)$, or $(4)$ can be converted into a conventional equation of a conic in one of the usual positions in Cartesian coordinates by assuming that $A$ has coordinates $\left(-\frac12,0\right)$
and $B$ has coordinates $\left(\frac12,0\right).$
If the coordinates of an arbitrary point $C$ on the conic are $(x,y)$,
then $a^2 = \left(x + \frac12\right)^2 + y^2$
and $b^2 = \left(x - \frac12\right)^2 + y^2.$
As shown [in the previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4430863/139123),
this implies that $(a^2 - b^2)^2 = 4x^2$ and $a^2 + b^2 = 2x^2 + 2y^2 + \tfrac12.$
We can substitute these expressions for $(a^2 - b^2)^2$ and $a^2 + b^2$
in any of the Equations $(2)$, $(3)$, or $(4)$
in order to obtain an equation in $x$ and $y$ that can be plotted in Cartesian coordinates. For example, Equation $(4)$ is equivalent to

$$
(4 d^2 - 1) 4x^2 + (2 - 8 d^4)\left(2x^2 + 2y^2 + \tfrac12\right)
 = 1 + 4 d^2 - 8 d^4,
$$

which is equivalent to
$$
4 d^2 (1 - d^2)x^2 + (1 - 4d^4)y^2 = d^2(1 - d^2).
$$

---

There are two special cases that still do not work out quite the way I think the question was looking for, namely the "degenerate ellipse" and the "degenerate hyperbola."
For example, using Equation $(4)$ we would expect to obtain the degenerate ellipse when $C' = O$ (that is, $d = 0$) and the degenerate hyperbola when $C'$ is exactly opposite from $O$ on the circle (that is, when $d = 1$).
But when $d = 0,$ Equation $(4)$ becomes
$$
-(a^2 - b^2)^2 + 2(a^2 + b^2) = 1,
$$
whereas when $d = 1$ the equation is
$$
3(a^2 - b^2)^2 - 6(a^2 + b^2) = -3.
$$
But the second equation is exactly equivalent to the first one.
In fact, both of these equations are equivalent to
$$
((a - b)^2 - 1)((a + b)^2 - 1) = 0,
$$
although it takes some algebra to get there.
When the first factor is zero, that is, when $(a - b)^2 = 1,$ you get a point on the "degenerate hyperbola,"
and when the second factor is zero, that is, when $(a + b)^2 = 1,$ you get a point on the "degenerate ellipse."

I do not think it is possible for one formula to continuously transform from the formula of the "degenerate ellipse" through the usual ellipses and hyperbolas to the formula of the "degenerate hyperbola."
One reason is that if you make the substitution
$a^2 = \left(x + \frac12\right)^2 + y^2$, $b^2 = \left(x - \frac12\right)^2 + y^2$
into such a formula, you should get a formula for the Cartesian coordinates of the conic. In order to be a correct formula for the non-degenerate conics, this formula must be a quadratic polynomial in $x$ and $y.$ But there is no quadratic polynomial in $x$ and $y$ that produces a line segment or two opposite rays.
One reason for that is that there is no way to produce such figures by intersecting an infinite double circular cone with an infinite plane.
(For this same reason, neither figure is usually considered to be an actual conic,
even in generalized contexts where we consider two parallel lines to be a conic.)

What you *can* produce by intersecting an infinite double circular cone with an infinite plane is a single line in the plane.
This happens when the vertex of the cone is on the plane and the plane is tangent to one of the circular cross-sections of the cone.
And a single line through the points $A$ and $B$ is what is produced as the graph of the equation when either $d = 0$ or $d = 1.$

If you really want to include in your taxonomy the non-conic curves that you call a "degenerate ellipse" and a "degenerate hyperbola," I think the best policy to set them aside as special cases to be handled by separate equations.
These two equations can be combined into the general equation of the line through $A$ and $B,$ which is a case of the general equation for all the other figures,
but to have a general equation that suddenly reduces to one of these two separate equations exactly when the parameter reaches the appropriate end of its range,
I think you would need to resort to at least one inelegant discontinuous function defined by cases, which would be a lot uglier than just defining the cases that you want in the obvious way. (One equation for $d = 0,$ one for $d = 1,$ and another for every other value of $d.$)